# Packaging an application from a folder which doesn't exist in source control

Tags: tfsbuild, octopus-deploy

I have a build which creates a `dist` folder (or similar) in TFS.

I'd like to package this up and deploy it as a zip file via Octopus.

At the moment, the `Package Application` octopus build task asks me to point to a folder in source control.

`$/MyProject/src/dist` for example

Does this folder have to exist in source control? or can I just type a random path and have it packaged up post build?

Answer (score 1):

The Package Application task is not asking for a location in source control just the location of the source code to package, so in your example it will be the `dist` directory.

There's a good description of the fields in the [Extension Marketplace page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octopusdeploy.octopus-deploy-build-release-tasks)

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Interesting, I will give this a go, at the moment the containing directory IS in source control, so I believe I can workaround by packaging `$\MyProject\src` folder and then working inside that during the deployment